Failed capture of amounts in transaction table
I have not been able to extract all the information from a table of debit and credit transactions.
The following is the table:

I have used several approaches and ideas with regular expressions, but I haven’t achieved satisfactory results, especially for the 'Concept' column and the amounts in 'Debit Amount' and 'Credit Amount,' where an operation can only be either a credit or a debit, so the appearance of one results in a blank value in the other.
I need to extract the table of financial transactions across the 23 pages of the PDF, and I need to extract exactly all the columns. About the columns:
'Transaction Date' and 'Accounting Date,' both in the “dd/mm/yy” format.
The 'Card' column, which can have two types of values: either blank "NA" or a number. In this case, the number will always be 24, but we should account for the possibility of other numbers.
'Document' consists entirely of numeric values.
'Concept' is an alphanumeric column, always starting with uppercase characters, and it can also contain numbers and symbols like “-”, “_”, and “+”. All the information in this column and the others must be retained, and it’s essential to understand that the 'Concept' column can be very long, such as “DEPOSITS - JSUTO JOSE MEJIA CONTRERAS PAYMENT CANON LB2253 3101571871,” which might cause the text to wrap onto a new line (but not a new row) in the document due to its length.
'Debit Amount' and 'Credit Amount,' the last two columns, contain numeric values. Since this is a financial analysis, each row will have either a 'Debit Amount' or a 'Credit Amount,' but not both. The appearance of one leaves the other blank, which is normal since the operation is either a credit or a debit. It’s essential to note that for 'Debit Amount' and 'Credit Amount,' the values will always use the dot “.” as the decimal symbol and the comma “,” for thousands, millions, or higher amounts.
So far, I have the following code, which works correctly for the first four columns, but I haven’t managed to extract the last three columns correctly, particularly the credit and debit amounts.
Could anyone guide or help me, please?
The document is available for download at the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ftbIvlgN927GqWFJEXOIYSOphBx3DWif/view?usp=sharing
Thank you very much!
For now, this is my code:
# Libraries

import os
import pandas as pd
import re
from unidecode import unidecode
import unicodedata
import pdfplumber
from IPython.display import display
import plotly.express as px

# WorkSpace

workspace_path = r"C:\Users\Oscar Centeno\Desktop\Oscar\CGR\2024\Ingresosnotributarios\data"
os.chdir(workspace_path)

print(f"Directorio actual: {os.getcwd()}")
print("Archivos en el espacio de trabajo:", os.listdir(workspace_path))

# Data ingestion

pdf_filename1 = "Estado cuenta BCR cta 242 Diciembre 2023.pdf"
pdf_filename2 = "11. NOVIEMBRE BNCR INGRESOS COLONES.pdf"

# Reg 

# Patrón de expresión regular para fechas, tarjeta y documento
date_tarjeta_documento_pattern = r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})\s*(24)?\s+(\d+)'

with pdfplumber.open(pdf_filename1) as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        # Buscar todas las instancias de fechas consecutivas, tarjeta opcional, y documento numérico
        matches = re.findall(date_tarjeta_documento_pattern, text)
        for match in matches:
            # Verificar si el tercer grupo (tarjeta) está vacío y asignar 'Na' si es así
            tarjeta = match[2] if match[2] == '24' else "Na"
            data.append({
                "Fecha Movimiento": match[0],
                "Fecha Contable": match[1],
                "Tarjeta": tarjeta,
                "Documento": match[3]  # El cuarto grupo captura el número de documento
            })

# Convert into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



I would suggest splitting the data by column first and then doing regex manipulation, rather than trying to come up with one huge pattern that parses all the data at once.

You should have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79038821/20436111 about pdfplumber because they are some settings you can use to modify the way the table is interpreted.

After the link on the last comment, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129168/pdfplumber-omits-rightmost-column-in-table/79153136#79153136 they have drawn vertical lines on a png. This shows them where those lines are needed to define the table. and then they have told pdfplumber to use those lines when extracting the table.
